# Как передать запрос методом POST в Python файл views.py?

Tags: django

Разрабатываю сайт на django.
Есть следующая форма:

```html
<form action="/external/" method="POST">
    <div id="profile"></div>
        <input type="button" value="добавить" onclick="addInput()">
        <input type="button" value="создать массив" onclick="func()">
        <input type="submit" value="Выполнить">
    </form>
```

Функция addInput():

```js
let i = 0;
    function addInput() {
  if (i < 5) {
    i = i + 1;
    let profile = document.getElementById('profile');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<label>Значение:</label> <input type="text" name="items[]" id="box' + (i + 1) + '">';
    profile.append(ip);
  }
        }
```

При нажатии на кнопку "добавить" появляется поле для ввода, по условию кол-во полей ограничено до 5. Для каждого поля id увеличивается на 1. name остается неизменным.

Функция func():

```js
function func() {
  let box = document.getElementsByName('items[]');
  let items = [];
 for(n=0; n < box.length; n++){
        let content = box[n].value
        items.push(content)
    }
    console.log(items)
}
```

Создает массив из значений, которые ввел пользователь в поле text тега input.
Все работает прекрасно, НО! Как передать сформированный массив из значений методом POST? В файле views.py лежит функция:

```
def external(request):
    items = request.POST.getlist('items[]')
    run([sys.executable, 'codetest.py', items])
    return render(request, 'main/test.html')
```

при нажатии на кнопку "выполнить" переменная items принимает только одно, последнее введенное значение пользователем, а нужно, чтобы принимала именно полученный массив, который далее должен быть принят в качестве аргумента в скрипте с последующей передачей запроса в БД. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

1. мне кажется у тебя ошибка в функции `addInput()` вместо `profile.append(ip)` должно быть `profile.append(div)`
2. Нет необходимости добавлять `[]`  к имени элемента, django итак по request.POST.getlist выдаст тебе список из введенных значений.
3. Как-то дополнительно заморачиваться для передачи массива значений не нужно. У тебя в html коде есть форма и указан метод `post`, соответственно все данные формы, которые ты заполнил автоматически уйдут на сервер как только ты нажмешь на кнопку с `submit` и ты сможешь получить их значения в `django`

Comment: Ввожу например 3 значения, нажимаю кнопку "выполнить" 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzr87.jpg

на сервер прилетает только последнее введенное значение "zzz":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsLEY.jpg

а необходим массив всех введенных значений.

Comment: вторую картинку откуда получил? может там не верно отображается информация(там похоже выдается `request.POST.get("items[]")` а не `request.POST.getlist("items[]")`). Я себе смоделировал ситуацию, добавил твою форму и код Javascript в итоге `request.POST.getlist("items[]")` выдает все значения которые передавались. Если у тебя выдает ошибку при отправке формы, добавь `{% csrf_token %}` после `<form method=...>`